# Semantic UI checkbox validation

Tags: semantic-ui

I've discovered an issue with Semantic UI validation of checkboxes and to illustrate I've created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/b5y35o8q/). This is the markup:

```
<form class="ui form segment">
  <p>Tell Us About Checkboxes</p>
  <div class="inline fields">
    <label>How often do you use checkboxes?</label>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency">
        <label>Once a week</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency">
        <label>2-3 times a week</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency">
        <label>Once a day</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio">
        <input type="radio" name="frequency">
        <label>Twice a day</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui blue submit button">Submit</div>
</form>
```

And this is the validation:

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui.checkbox").checkbox();
  $('.ui.form').form({
      "inline": true,
      "on": "blur",
      "fields": {
        "frequency": {
          "identifier": 'frequency',
          "rules": [{
            "type": 'checked',
            "prompt": 'Please select when you use checkboxes'
          }]
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Basically I need to validate that a single checkbox has been checked (for some reason the JSFiddle has them all checked initially...?) and that check of validation works really well when someone clicks the first radio but if you try to hit a radio other than the first one it doesn't remove the error. Anyone any idea what's going on?

Comment: Is this the behaviour that you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/cydhgz11/

Comment: Hi there, no that's not quite right but thanks for the pointer on removing the checkbox class in order to remove the checked status - that really did make me scratch my head! The issue is on validation of the radio. If the first is checked then the error class is removed and the form can be submitted - if other radio buttons are checked then the validation doesn't get removed. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

Updating from Semantic UI 2.0.4 to 2.1.8/latest fixes all of your problems.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js">
</script>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hnz6ks45/1/

---

This issue appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3556) in the Semantic UI project's GitHub repository. There is also a [history](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2505) of [issues](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2501) that stretches back about a year.

Until the developer(s) fix whatever the problem is, I suggest that you check one of the radios by default (**`checked="checked"`**), as this seems to remove the issue.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bnugf1d3/

Also, I suggest you amend each `<div class="ui radio">` to be `<div class="ui radio checkbox">` i.e. include the class "checkbox" on each div with classes "ui radio" so that they will benefit from Semantic UI's custom styling [(see docs example)](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#radio).

Finally, I suggest adding a `for` attribute to each of your labels for the purposes of accessibility. The additional advantage is that your users will be able to manipulate the checkboxes/radios by clicking the text adjacent to the radios, not just the radios themselves, which are fairly small and require more precision thence more thought to click. This will mean adding an `id` to each `input` element as I demonstrate below:

```html
<div class="required inline fields">
    <label>How often do you use checkboxes?</label>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" id="freq_1" name="frequency" checked="checked">
        <label for="freq_1">Once a week</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" id="freq_2" name="frequency">
        <label for="freq_2">2-3 times a week</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" id="freq_3" name="frequency">
        <label for="freq_3">Once a day</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" id="freq_4" name="frequency">
        <label for="freq_4">Twice a day</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @amdouglas, I'd spent ages looking through git and managed not to find that issue! You comments about the labels are quite correct but the JSFiddle was merely a demonstration, thanks though. I did have `checkbox` class on them but they were all selected...? My use case dictates that I can't have one pre-selected I'm afraid - but a handy work-around. If I get no other joy I'll accept your answer at the end of the bounty! Thanks again!

Comment: Well, your use case must be addressed properly, and to that end, I have updated with a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hnz6ks45/1/

Comment: From 2.2.0 to the latest version available (2.4.2) the bug reappeared.